# Selector Objective-C setting

Tags: objective-c, ios, selector

I'm making a custom button in Objective-C, GLButton. I want to follow the Target-Action Design Pattern. So in GLButton I have

```
SEL _action;
NSObject *_target;

- (void) setAction:(SEL) action{
    _action = action;
} 

- (void) setTarget:(NSObject*) target{
    _target = target;
}
```

and to perform the action it calls

```
[_target performSelector:_action];
```

In the class that instantiates GLButton I have the methods

```
- (void) button1{
    NSLog(@"button1");
}

- (void) button2{
    NSLog(@"button2");
}
```

I then set the respective target/action

```
[b1 setTarget:self];
[b1 setAction:@selector(button1)];
[b2 setTarget:self];
[b2 setAction:@selector(button2)];
```

but when I click either button it always fires the last target set, in this case button2.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Where have you declared `_action` and `_target`? Did you just declare them globally at the top of the file?

Comment: In the `@interface` of your `GLButton` class, add an `@property (nonatomic) NSObject *target`, and a similar property for `action`. At the top of the implementation, add `@synthesize target = _target, action = _action`, then remove your custom set methods completely. See if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these instance variables or declared at a random place in your .m files?

```
SEL _action;
NSObject *_target;
```

They need to be instance variables or, better yet, @property declarations.

Comment: They were meant to be instance variables. For some reason I thought selectors couldn't be properties. Putting both as properties fixed it. Brain Fart

Comment: @BrianSherman in future, remember that when you declare variables randomly at the top your source file, they are *global* variables, that is, they exist in one universal instance, so setting them from one instance of the class will change them everywhere.